# How to remove or hide message in form validation

Tags: forms, zend-framework

I don't want to show message after label when validate form.
my code is

```
$name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
$name->setLabel('Name:')
$name->setOptions(array('size' => '35'))
$name->setRequired(true)
$name->addValidator('NotEmpty', true)
$name->addValidator('Alnum', true)            
$name->addFilter('HTMLEntities')            
$name->addFilter('StringTrim') 
$name->removeDecorator('Errors')
$name->setDecorators($this->elementDecorators);
```

but it still show error message after label.
How can I fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

remove  'Errors' decorator from element decorator after setDecorator method.